# How to determine the movement using only two frames

Tags: image-processing, tracking, motion-detection

I'm learning the moving object detection using a sequence of frames.

This is an example of two frames. I need to select moved object in the right frame.

I can subtract one frame from another. In the selected area the result would be none zero => that was a movement in that area.  But if u look at the right frame, u could see a background selected as well.

Can I somehow separate the car from the background?

[image]

i guess the method, when we collecting the background pixels, and than subtract the image from the background is useless on a two frames, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the method does not work very well with only two frames. The method you describe works best when you have one image with only background, which you can then use to compare with new images to look for movement.

It is possible to calculate the movement of the object with only two frames, but then you probably need more advanced methods, such as [optical flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) or [image registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) algorithms.

Comment: And what about the subtracting of two frames. In the SELECTED AREA, pixels, where the difference of subtracting is more than e - belongs to a background. The others - to the object.

Will it be working in a case of cars detection?

Comment: It could kind of work, especially for cars, since they are often homogenous looking. However, you would get some problems in areas of big differences, like the number plate. If you subtract the two images above, you will get a region of high difference in the road behind the car, but also where the number plate is... It will be a lot easier if you can get a photo of the road without any car, and then use that as your background.

Comment: that is not possible to get the background in my case! Thx a lot for your answer, it was very usefull!